# C4838 warning with array initialization of a const char* array

Tags: c++, arrays, char, constants, warnings

For a project I compile my shaders to binary data and then convert them to a header file that declares the byte code of the shader as a `const char` array.

However, during compilation I get the following warning:

> "conversion from `int` to `const char` requires a narrowing
>   conversion".

Now I normally know why this happens, it's because the compiler thinks the values are of type `int`, while they are in fact declared as a type of `char`.

```
const char base_ps[]={
0x44,0x58,0x42,0x43,0x12 ... etc
```

When hovering over these values *IntelliSense* also points out these are casted to an `int`. For instance, for the value at index `0` it lists `(int)0x44`.

Is there any work around for this? Obviously I can explicity put (`char`) everywhere before each value, however I'd have to add an extra step into shader generation for this that parses the header file.

I kind of don't want to suppress the warning either, yet I want warnings treated as errors. Any advice on this?

Comment: Do you still get the warning if you use something like `const char foo[] = "\x44\x58\x42\x43";`?

Comment: Also, `'\x44', '\x58', '\x42', '\x43', '\x12'`...

Comment: Strange, I [couldn't reproduce this](http://rextester.com/RWEKWO65324)

Comment: Hm, that's odd. Is it maybe the warning level? I'm generating my project using CMake and I'm not sure what the default warning level is.

Here it doesn't work; http://rextester.com/IIE43940 Maybe it's the way it's declared?

Comment: Also @NathanOliver I don't get the warning then. Just when declared as 0x..

Comment: Is one of the values `0x80` or greater? If so, do you also get the warning if you remove all such values?

Comment: @user3001604: You are correctly getting a narrowing warning because the values you are providing are larger than what can be stored in a byte. Anything larger than `0x7F` is too big. So al lthe `0xFF` are overflowing.

Comment: @user3001604: [See what I mean here](http://rextester.com/DGUD88641). No warnings, no values over `0x7F`

Comment: Oh wow, seems I'll have to go back to my basics hey. I didn't realise there were values bigger than 127 in there. I kind of forgot that the array was signed. Thanks guys!

P.S. Why does @NathanOliver's example work in that case, even though it's still a signed char array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you are actually using hex values that are too large to store in a `char` (which is usually signed and 8 bits long). So the largest positive value is 127, or `0x7F`. The values you are providing [like you show here](http://rextester.com/IIE43940) include values over 127, hence you get a correct narrowing conversion warning.

Either use an `unsigned char` instead of `char`, or use smaller numbers (not larger than 0x7F) [like here](http://rextester.com/DGUD88641):

```
const char deferred_ps[]={
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f, 
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
    0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f,
    0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f,
    0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f,
    0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f,
    0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f,
    0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f
};
```

Note that if you ignore the narrowing conversion warning, the result is implementation-defined, which is non-portable.

Comment: Why would there be signed integer overflow? That's conversion between int and char and that's implementation defined AFAIK.

Comment: @ftfish: When the compiler warns you about a narrowing conversion, it means that you going from a type that is larger (in terms of bits) to a type that is smaller in terms of bits. It's true that whether `char` is signed or not is implementation defined. Many implementations choose for it to be signed. Therefore there is a risk of signed integer overflow.

Comment: There is a conversion from int to char, I know. However, this conversion is well-defined if the destination is unsigned or the destination can hold the source value and implementation-defined otherwise, but not undefined. For a reference, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). Quote: _If the destination type is signed, the value does not change if the source integer can be represented in the destination type. Otherwise the result is implementation-defined. (Note that this is different from signed integer arithmetic overflow, which is undefined)._

Comment: @ftfish: You're right that the standard says implementation-defined. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress the warning by using a [character literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_literal) instead [integer literal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_literal).  With character literals you can use the [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) in the form of `\xNN` to denote a character defined by a hexadecimal value.  That would look like

```
const char foo[] = "\x44\x58\x42\x43";
```

or

```
const char foo[] = {'\x44', '\x58', '\x42', '\x43'};
```

The difference between them is that since the first one is a c string it will add a null terminator to the end.  If you do not want that then you need to use the second method.

Comment: This clears up quite a bit on why it presumes it's an integer. I might as well just write up a post generation step that parses the header and changes all the entries to the provided char literal format. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3001604 No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: @user3001604 You might want to consider accepting Andy's answer since it has the real reason why you were getting the warning.

Comment: Then again, why does it alao work to make everything a character literal?

Comment: @user3001604 It silently disables it.  The compiler is allowed to do whatever you want if you give it a hex value that is larger than the representable range: *[...]A sequence of octal or hexadecimal digits is terminated by the first character that is not an octal digit or a hexadecimal digit, respectively. The value of a character literal is implementation-defined if it falls outside of the implementation-defined range defined for[...]*

Comment: All right, thanks for all the input. Learned something haha.